# How to type nested objects using Object.keys()?

Tags: typescript, nested-object

I am using the nested object and trying to get to the properties using Object.keys() and forEach().
The problem is when I want to get to the nested keys filteringState[item][el].

How to type function like this?

```
interface InitialStateTypes {
    country: {
        "italy": boolean,
    },
    board: {
        "full": boolean,
    },
    transport: {
        "bus": boolean,
        "own": boolean
    },
}

interface FilteringDataTypes {
    country: string[],
    board: string[],
    transport: string[],
}

const collectFilteringData = (filteringState: InitialStateTypes) => {
    let filteringData = <FilteringDataTypes>{};

    Object.keys(filteringState).forEach((item) => {
        Object.keys(filteringState[item]).forEach((el) => {
            if (filteringState[item][el]) {
                if (!filteringData[item]) {
                    filteringData[item] = [el];
                } else {
                    filteringData[item] = [...filteringData[item], el];
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return filteringData;
};


export default collectFilteringData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can get a little messy when using the `keys` method, because it only expects to output strings. (It is not unreasonable since JS Object keys are considered strings, of course TypeScript worries about this more)

Below is a possible way it could be done:

```js
interface InitialStateTypes {
  country: {
      "italy": boolean,
  },
  board: {
      "full": boolean,
  },
  transport: {
      "bus": boolean,
      "own": boolean
  },
}

interface FilteringDataTypes {
  country: string[],
  board: string[],
  transport: string[],
}

const collectFilteringData = (filteringState: InitialStateTypes):FilteringDataTypes => {
  let filteringData = {} as FilteringDataTypes

  (Object.keys(filteringState) as Array<keyof InitialStateTypes>).forEach((item) => {
      (Object.keys(filteringState[item]) as Array<keyof InitialStateTypes[typeof item]>).forEach((el) => {
          if (filteringState[item][el]) {
              if (!filteringData[item]) {
                  filteringData[item] = [el];
              } else {
                  filteringData[item] = [...filteringData[item], el];
              }
          }
      });
  });
  return filteringData;
};


export default collectFilteringData
```

- Here the type assertion acts to tell TypeScript the types you're actually expecting.
- It then allows the correct types to be passed through to the `forEach` method
- The tricky part is that it's nested, so you have to do another type assertion, **but** you also want to pass in the value for the `typeof item` from the first `forEach`

Formatted (with Prettier), it ends up looking like this:

```js
const collectFilteringData = (
  filteringState: InitialStateTypes
): FilteringDataTypes => {
  let filteringData = {} as FilteringDataTypes;

  (Object.keys(filteringState) as Array<keyof InitialStateTypes>).forEach(
    (item) => {
      (
        Object.keys(filteringState[item]) as Array<
          keyof InitialStateTypes[typeof item]
        >
      ).forEach((el) => {
        if (filteringState[item][el]) {
          if (!filteringData[item]) {
            filteringData[item] = [el];
          } else {
            filteringData[item] = [...filteringData[item], el];
          }
        }
      });
    }
  );
  return filteringData;
};
```

##### Note

I've written this answer as of TypeScript 4.6.2, the `keys` method is typed like so:

```js
keys(o: object): string[];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `keyof` operator.

Example :

```
type Point = { x: number; y: number };
type P = keyof Point;
```

Here is more details : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Nested data :

```
type Point = { test: {x: number; y: number} };
type P = keyof Point["test"];
```

Comment: Yes keyof is working but only for first level of properties inside the InitialStateTypes. How can I type next level of nesting.

Comment: @BartD I added info in my post. Could this do the trick for you ?